# Android : How to Allow Only One Touch?

Tags: android, touch, multi-touch

How to allow only one touch on Android? I don't want to support multi-touch and I want my app to discard other touches if my one of my fingers is already touching the screen. It's like using exclusive touch on iOS.

Also, is there a way to set the number of touches allowed?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Minimum target API = 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to keep track of the pointer id of the first touch and use only the touch events corressponding to that touch. Here is good example from  [The official Android blog "Making Sense of Multitouch "](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html)

```
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

// The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

// Existing code ...

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        // Save the ID of this pointer
        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
        final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
        final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
        final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

        final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
        final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

        mPosX += dx;
        mPosY += dy;

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        invalidate();
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
        final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
            mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, I added it on my activity but it doesn't recognized the touch from a fragment inside the activity. How should I do it? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to do this by using the id of the objects i was setting with my ontouchlistener and it got me into trouble.  This was perfect.

Comment: So, in IOS, you say "view.isExclusiveTouch = true;" ... and in Android, you have to use the above code?  I refuse to believe this.

Answer (score 3):

yes you can disable the multi-touch by using this `android:splitMotionEvents="false"` or `android:windowEnableSplitTouch="false"`

Comment: Not sure if this works. But it requires API level 11 and above.

Comment: The minimum version I'm targeting is API 10.